# Office.FileDialog not performing as I expected

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I gave up on named ranges, switching to the built-in import from Excell tool. When it comes to selecting the spreadsheet to import, the open file dialog won't work. Yes, I added the required reference, when prompted.
According to all the documentation I have read, this should work:

```
Dim FilePath As Variant
Dim dlg As Office.FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With dlg
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select Log Sheet"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Select Log Sheet", "*.xlsx"
    If .Show = True Then
        FilePath = dlg.SelectedItems
    Else
        MsgBox "You Clicked Cancel"
    End If
 End With
```

however, when it gets to `.Filters.Add`, I get

> "Object doesn't support the property or method"

I'm starting to think Access hates me. I came out of retirement to write a quick log sheet processing app and the struggle with Access is getting annoying.
Thanks for any help. By the way, the next step is to feed the returned file to the saved import, and so far I've not seen how to pass a file argument to it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using msoFileDialogFolderPicker dialog,
This is for selecting a folder (not a file) and thus doesn't support filtering of file type (as you are attempting to do).

Suggest using msoFileDialogFilePicker instead. This is for getting a target file path (which is what your code implies you're after).

Separately, you have a second bug and can trim your code a tad (as shown below).
Note the use of `.SelectedItems(1)` and doing away with setting a dialog object:

```
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select Log Sheet"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Select Log Sheet", "*.xlsx"
        
        If .Show = True Then
            FilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You Clicked Cancel"
        End If
     
     End With
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now for my next trick, pass the filepath to the saved import a nd call it

Comment: _that worked_ ... then please mark as answered.